# ReduxForm: selection <option /> not reacting to error

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to add validation to my Redux Form.

This workes great for all my components that use a regular input or textarea case im building a custom component for like...

Since here I'm able to grab the args added to my renderField and work with these values. But on my selection list, I'm having another approach so im not sure on how to excess the `.meta.error && .meta.touched`

```
renderField(field) {
    if (field) {
      return (
        <div className="field">
          <div className="control">
            <label className="label">{field.label}</label>
            <field.type
              className={field.type}
              type={field.textType}
              {...field.input}
            />
            {field.meta.touched &&
              field.meta.error && (
                <p className="error">
                  <i className="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true" />
                  {field.meta.error}
                </p>
              )}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }  

render(){
 return(
   <Field
     label="Title"
     name="title"
     type="input"
     textType="text"
     component={this.renderField}
   />
 )
}
```

But I also have a selection list and here I can't get it to work with it.

```
<div className="field">
                <div className="control">
                  <label className="label">Category</label>
                  <Field name="category" className="select" component="select">
                    <option value={false} />
                    {categories.map(c => (
                      <option key={c.name} value={c.path}>
                        {c.name}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </Field>
                </div>
              </div>
              {/* This needs to be inserted here some how...

                {field.meta.touched &&
                  field.meta.error && (
                    <p className="error">
                      <i className="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true" />
                      {field.meta.error}
                    </p>
                  )}
                */}
```

Validation looks like.

```
function validate(values) {
  const errors = {}
  if (!values.title || values.title.length < 5) {
    errors.title = 'Please enter a title with at least 5 characters'
  }

  if (!values.author) {
    errors.author = "What's your name?"
  }

  if (values.category === '') {
    errors.category = 'What category does the following fit in?'
  }

  if (!values.body) {
    errors.body = 'What Would You Like To Share?'
  }
  return errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a function for renderSelect aswell.

```
  renderSelect(field) {
    if (field) {
      return (
        <div className="field">
          <div className="control">
            <label className="label">{field.label}</label>
            <select className="select" {...field.input}>
              <option />
              {field.data.map(c => (
                <option key={c.name} value={c.path}>
                  {c.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
            {field.meta.touched &&
              field.meta.error && (
                <p className="error">
                  <i className="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true" />
                  {field.meta.error}
                </p>
              )}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

---

```
<Field
 label="Category"
 name="category"
 data={categories}
 component={this.renderSelect}
>
```